# To read the HTTP responseText of a particular event (or for all the responses) from my website through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, httpresponse

Is it possible to read all the HTTP Request/Responses' header and body in a webpage through javascript or through any of its framework?

[Screenshot of the required field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlcJY.png) (opens in the same window)

For example:- Like the way I could view/copy them, through my browser's developer tools.

To my understanding, if I could get hold onto an object or event that fires these requests then I can access the responseText property to fulfill my requirement.

My question is how do I do that? Is it even possible to get all the responseText for all the responses received in my webpage?

(As it has been rendered successfully, then possibly I should be able to access them as well, isn't it?)

I'm just a beginner, so not sure if my question is meaningful. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes @jdphenix, I tried that solution and I did not get the expected result, so I raised this question to clarify.
I got this result though.
'content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: fri, 25 nov 2016 04:26:05 gmt
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 3102'

How can I get more details from the headers? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Also is it possible to read the response body of a particular request's response through the script?
How to get an object of a particular request/response, in order to access responseText?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're asking how to retrieve detailed network traffic information for a given website. This is browser specific: Chrome for example exposes the `chrome.devtools.network` object which you can interrogate. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network

Comment: Thanks for your effort.
I have updated the question and the comments in other replies.
Your answer is correct as well. I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following javascript code:

```
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', document.location, false);
    req.send(null);
    var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
    alert(headers);
```

it will get all the HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @knjght0011.

I tried that solution and I did not get the expected result, so I raised this question to clarify.
I got this result though -
'content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: fri, 25 nov 2016 04:26:05 gmt
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 3102'

How can I get more details from the headers? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Also is it possible to read the response body of a particular request's response through the script?
How to get an object of a particular request/response, in order to access responseText?